# Why doesn't this Jest test fail?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs

Below can be tried out live at https://repl.it/@SandraSchlichti/jest-playground-3#getStatusCode.test.js

Originally the below test had `status: 200`, but I tried to change it to `301` to see if I had understand how it worked.

```
  describe('when the server returns 200', () => {
    let result;
    //??? The desired purpose of this test is to have a mis-match between expected and
    //??? returned status code so getStatusCode() returns 0.
    //??? Trying to figure out how this test works.
    //??? Here I have changed status to 301 and expected the test to fail, but it didn't
    //??? From my understanding mockResponseData contains status 301, and status below
    //??? should override that? But that doesn't seam to be the case for some reason.
    beforeAll(async () => {
      axios.get.mockResolvedValue({
        status: 301,
        data: mockResponseData
      });
      result = await getStatusCode();
    });

    it('should return 0', () => {
      expect(result).toEqual(0)
    })
  });
```

## Question

I had expected the test to fail, when I changed it to `status: 301`, as `getStatusCode()` should return `1` when the status codes match.

1. Why doesn't the test fail?
2. Can the test be modified to make it more clear the expected and returned status codes doesn't match?
3. The order of `status` and `data` doesn't seam to matter for some reason. Why is that? Isn't `status: 301` suppose to override the `status` inside `mockResponseData`?
4. If I inside `mockResponseData.json` change `status` to `9999`, then all tests are unaffected. I get the feeling that the content in `mockResponseData.json` isn't used at all?

These are the files needed to try it out locally:

**mockedResponseData.json**

```
  {
    "status": 301,
    "statusText": "Moved Permanently",
    "headers": {
        "location": "https: //www.google.com/",
        "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
        "date": "Thu, 12 Nov 2020 10: 09: 41 GMT",
        "expires": "Sat, 12 Dec 2020 10: 09: 41 GMT",
        "cache-control": "public, max-age=2592000",
        "server": "gws",
        "content-length": "220",
        "x-xss-protection": "0",
        "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
        "alt-svc": "h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"",
        "connection": "close"
    }
}
```

**getStatusCode.test.js**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const getStatusCode = require('./getStatusCode');
const mockResponseData = require('./mockResponseData.json');

jest.mock("axios");

describe("getStatusCode ", () => {
  describe('when the server returns status code matching options.statusCode', () => {
    let result;
    beforeAll(async () => {
      axios.get.mockResolvedValue({
        status: 200,
        data: mockResponseData
      })
      result = await getStatusCode({
        statusCode: 200
      })
    });

    it('should return 1', () => {
      expect(result).toEqual(1)
    })
  });

  describe('when the server returns 200', () => {
    let result;
    //??? The desired purpose of this test is to have a mis-match between expected and returned status code,
    //??? getStatusCode() returns 0.
    //??? Trying to figure out how this test works.
    //??? Here I have changed status to 301 and expected the test to fail, but it didn't
    //??? From my understanding mockResponseData contains status 301, and status below should override that?
    //??? But that doesn't seam to be the case for some reason.
    beforeAll(async () => {
      axios.get.mockResolvedValue({
        status: 301,
        data: mockResponseData
      });
      result = await getStatusCode();
    });

    it('should return 0', () => {
      expect(result).toEqual(0)
    })
  });

  describe("when expected and returned status code doesn't match", () => {
    let result;
    beforeAll(async () => {
      // mockRejected value returns rejected promise
      // which will be handled by the try/catch
      axios.get.mockRejectedValue({
        status: 200,
        data: mockResponseData
      })
      result = await getStatusCode();
    })

    it('should return -1', () => {
      expect(result).toEqual(-1)
    })
  });

});
```

**getStatusCode.js**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('qs');

module.exports = async (options) => {
  options              = options || {};
  options.url          = options.url || {};
  options.statusCode   = options.statusCode || 0;
  options.timeout      = options.timeout || 1000;
  options.maxRedirects = options.maxRedirects || 0;

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(options.url, {
      timeout: options.timeout,
      maxRedirects: options.maxRedirects,
      // make all http status codes a success
      validateStatus: function (status) {
        return true;
      }
  });


    return (response.status === options.statusCode) ? 1 : 0;
  } catch (error) {
    return -1;
  }
};
```

Comment: @Andreas Now added.

Comment: In the test you pointed to, status is 301 and statusCode defaults to 0, 301 != 0, so it returns 0. Please, clarify, what exactly are your expectations and why.

Comment: Why does it default to zero, when I have provided an input argument of `status: 301`?

Comment: Because of `options.statusCode   = options.statusCode || 0`.  You provided `{ statusCode: 200 }` in one test but not in the other, hence the difference.

Comment: In the first code snippet in OP, is `status: 301` not treated as `options.statusCode`? Hence, it should not default to zero?

Comment: From what I see, the only way status and statusCode are connected is that they compared against each other in `return (response.status === options.statusCode) ? 1 : 0`. So `getStatusCode()` with no statusCode option will always return 0, unless response status is 0 (status 0 is reserved for client-side request errors but I don't remember if Axios follows the convention).

Answer (score 2):

When you don't pass any arguments to `result = await getStatusCode();` it will default to zero. If you don't want that, then do

```
describe('when the server returns 200', () => {
    let result;
    beforeAll(async () => {
      axios.get.mockResolvedValue({
        status: 301,
        data: mockResponseData
      });
      result = await getStatusCode({
          statusCode: 200                // <-----------
        });
    });

    it('should return 0', () => {
      expect(result).toEqual(0)
    })
  });
```